# How to create attached property for ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, itemscontrol, attached-properties

I have the following ItemsControl, as shown it has hard-coded values, I would like to shift these values into an attached property, probably an ObservableCollection or something similar.

How to create this attached property and how to bind it.

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="ItemsSelected">
    <sys:Double>30</sys:Double>
    <sys:Double>70</sys:Double>
    <sys:Double>120</sys:Double>
    <sys:Double>170</sys:Double>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Fill="SlateGray" Width="18" Height="4"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

[EDIT]
So I think I have the attached property figured:

```
public static class ScrollBarMarkers
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MarkersSelectedCollectionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MarkersSelectedCollection", typeof(ObservableCollection<double>), typeof(ScrollBarMarkers), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static ObservableCollection<double> GetMarkersSelectedCollection(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ObservableCollection<double>)obj.GetValue(MarkersSelectedCollectionProperty);
    }

    public static void SetMarkersSelectedCollection(ItemsControl obj, ObservableCollection<double> value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(MarkersSelectedCollectionProperty, value);
    }
}
```

What I'm wondering now is the best way to get the ItemsControl object before calling the following in the selection changed behavior:

```
ScrollBarMarkers.SetMarkersSelectedCollection(ItemsControl, initSelected);
```

The style of the customized vertical scrollbar is setup in the Window.Resources

The behavior is set up on the DataGrid like so:

```
<DataGrid Name="GenericDataGrid">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <helpers:DataGridSelectionChanged />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</DataGrid>
```

My selection changed behavior:

```
public class DataGridSelectionChanged : Behavior<DataGrid>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        this.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += DataGrid_SelectionChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        this.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= DataGrid_SelectionChanged;
    }

    void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<double> initSelected = new ObservableCollection<double>();
        initSelected.Add(30);
        initSelected.Add(60);
        initSelected.Add(100);
        //Just trying to figure out how best to get the ItemsControl object.
        ScrollBarMarkers.SetMarkersSelectedCollection(itemsControlObj, initSelected);
    }
}
```

Below is an example of the markers in the scrollbar, a ItemsControl has been added to the custom vertical scrollbar as per the code right at the top of the question.
[image]

Comment: There is no need for an attached property... Just create your *ObservableCollection<T>* and populate it with entries (similar as you would create and fill an *List<T>*) -- then assign/bind the collection to the `ItemsSource` property of the ItemsControl. (Or did i misunderstand your intention?)

Comment: I could have put more detail. I have a custom vertical scrollbar in a DataGrid, this ItemsControl is eventually going be placing markers wherever there is selected items. The best place for this collection is going to be as an attached property, also there are going behaviors that will update the collection. My confusion comes from: I haven't created an attached property with ObservableCollection and when binding to one, it has always had objects so the binding has been the objects properties, this is going to be straight to the primitive.

Comment: But why can't you use the ItemsControl.ItemsSource property for that? (i still try to understand the context of your problem -- i have seen from your other questions that you already know how to make use of ItemsControl.ItemsSource, so i guess i still fail to get a grasp on your problem)

Comment: Sorry binding to the ItemsSource should be fine, but as above in the ItemContainerStyle there a <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding}" /> won't this binding change?

Comment: The binding should work the same, no matter if you have specified the item values in XAML (as in your question), or whether the values are in a collection assigned/bound to the ItemsSource property of the ItemsControl...

Comment: Thankyou that clears that up. I have made an Edit above evolving the question.

Comment: Now, i don't know about the relationship between the DataGrid and the ItemsControl with respect to the visual+logical tree, but could it be possible to just declare an DependencyProperty in your behaviour (of type ItemsControl) and bind the ItemsControl to it? (On further thought, this behaviour should actually be a Behavior<ItemsControl> - i.e., it does manipulate the ItemsControl and not the DataGrid, as it seems.)

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines with the DependencyProperty, not so sure on the behavior as it stands the behavior above works well whenever something in the DataGrid is selected, I've removed other code manipulates the DataGrid.... The datagrid does have two ItemsControls, one for the actual items and one for the vertical scrollbar, your not getting these confused are you? Posted an image to show mockup.

Comment: I would say give it a try with the DP...

Comment: I have added the DependencyProperty for type ItemsControl. Just having an issue binding the actual ItemsControl in XAML. I've have tried: <helpers:DataGridSelectionChanged ItemsControlObject="{Binding ElementName=ItemsSelected}" /> no luck

Comment: Run your program in the VS debugger. Look in the debug output window (menu Debug -> Windows -> Output) for any exceptions regarding the binding. Can you find anything there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went down the wrong track with this instead of creating a DependencyProperty I should have just created a plain property, however because it is UI related I did not want it with my ViewModel. So I created a class with singleton pattern in the same namespace as my behavior and other attached properties. This also means I can set the collection from any behaviors.

Here is the binding:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static helpers:MyClass.Instance}, Path=SelectedMarkers}">
```

Here is the class with singleton pattern

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static ObservableCollection<double> m_selectedMarkers = new ObservableCollection<double>();
    public ObservableCollection<double> SelectedMarkers
    {
        get
        {
            return m_selectedMarkers;
        }
        set
        {
            m_selectedMarkers = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    private static MyClass m_Instance;
    public static MyClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_Instance == null)
            {
                m_Instance = new MyClass();
            }

            return m_Instance;
        }
    }

    private MyClass()
    {
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want bind an ObservableCollection to ItemsControl and when the items are long the scrollbar will appear.

This solution could serve you.

[I will working with MVVM]

You can create a ObservableCollection in your code.

```
 private ObservableCollection<int> _list = new ObservableCollection<int>();
 public ObservableCollection<int> List
    {
        get { return _list ; }
        set { _list = value; RaisePropertyChanged("List"); }
    }
```

Now, you binding Collection to ItemsControl

```
<ScrollViewer  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="254" Height="Auto" >
            <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControlComputers" ItemsSource="{Binding List, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="Auto"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="254" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            Background="{x:Null}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="254">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" Margin="4,0,0,5" VerticalAlignment="Center">      
                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Not quite, if you have a look at the image above, you'll see that there are markers on the vertical scrollbar. These markers has been created with an ItemsControl and represent selected items within the DataGrid.

Comment: So, you want scrollbar for each element into ItemsControl?

Comment: If you want scrollbar appear, simply into ScrollViewer you put DataGrid...(Without need ItemsControl). 
Still I don't find relationship between DataGrid and ItemsControl